# Anime where villain traps the main character's group in looping hallways then fights them

Tags: story-identification, anime

I think I watched it sometime between 2006 and 2012; I only saw one bit of it.

The main character and his group notice that they've been traveling the same hallways and figure out that they loop. The villain (some guy with white hair) is watching them. The hallways were barren stone with steps leading up at the end. I think they got out by breaking through a wall. Leading out into a compound, and I think there were a bunch of white pillars or structures scattered around.

They confront the villain and his group.  (He's the only human-looking guy in it. The rest are these squat little round guys.)

He places his hand on one of their heads, then turns into a purple sphere.  The villain then proceeds to take bites out of it and transforms/powers up.

The guy that gets eaten has a large smile like kurosensei and he's in a suit. Think the guy that eats him sprouts something from his back.

Comment: Endless loops are pretty common; eating a subordinate isn't though... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnnaturallyLoopingLocation might have something?

Comment: I think I watched it sometime between 2006 and 2012. 
I'm less sure about these details, but I think they're mostly correct. The hallways were barren stone with steps leading up at the end. I think they got out by break through a wall. Leading out into a compound, and I think there were a bunch of white pillars or structures scattered around. The guy that gets eaten has a large smile like kurosensei and he's in a suit. Think the guy that eats him sprouts something from his back. Less sure of these details, but that's everything I remembered about the show. Only saw this one bit of it. @DavidW

Comment: Not sure if I tagged you correctly @DavidW

Comment: @Thishasbeenbuggingme Yep, it worked.  I'm going to [edit] the details from your comment into the question; feel free to fix it if I mess up.